# Accessing recently set property in state returns the old value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my model:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(3).fill(Array(3).fill(null)),
      xIsNext: true
    };
  }

  get turn() {
    return this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
  }

  handleTurn(x, y) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice().map(function(row) {
      return row.slice();
    });

    const turn = this.turn; // this returns either "X" or "Y"
    squares[x][y] = turn; // this is the value I'm going to be accessing later on
    this.setState({
      squares: squares
    });

    if (this.isSolved(x, y)) {
      console.log('VICTORY!')
    }
    this.nextPlayer();
  }
  isSolved(x, y) {
    var count = 0
    var player = this.state.squares[x][y]; // here is when I try to access the value set at at 'handleTurn')
    // more stuff down there
    return false;
}
```

My problem is this: `isSolved` is called from `handleTurn`, and in `handleTurn` I'll set up one of the coordinates from the bi-dimensional to either 'X' or 'Y'; but when I check that value in `isSolved`, I always get the *previous* value, not the one I just set.

E.g., on first call will get `null` (when I'd expect  `X`), second call and I'll get `X` (when I'd expect `O` by then), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In React `setState` [works (mostly) asynchronously](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) in order to be able to batch multiple changes in one pass.

That means, that when you `this.setState` in `handleTurn` the state has not actually been changed yet.

You can pass `setState` a second argument, which is a callback function you want to execute when the state is actually changed.

Here is an interesting article which goes into more depth on the behaviour of `setState`: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm